# DBT - Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT or keyword WITH but got keyword CREATE at

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I am trying to make an sql file in dbt in order to update models with a new column

```
{{
    config(materialized='table'
    , retain_previous_version_flg=false
    , migrate_data_over_flg=true
)
}}

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE {{ ref ('my_table') }} (
SELECT *, new_columns_ts TIMESTAMP
);
```

Is there a way to use CREATE directly rather than having to use SELECT or WITH clause?

```
Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT or keyword WITH but got keyword CREATE at [16:1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you don’t need to use the statement  CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE, to create a materialized table. You only need to write the SELECT statement.

> There are no create or replace statements written in model statements.
> This means that dbt does not offer methods for issuing CREATE TABLE
> statements which can be used for source tables.

You can see this [example](https://dataschool.com/sql-optimization/start-modeling-data/#:%7E:text=Creating%20a%20New%20Table%20with%20Modeled%20Data).

```
{{
    config(materialized='table'
    , retain_previous_version_flg=false
    , migrate_data_over_flg=true
)
}}


SELECT *, new_columns_ts TIMESTAMP from ‘dataset.table’
```

You can see this [option using SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#creating_a_new_table_from_an_existing_table).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE dataset.table (
SELECT *, new_columns_ts TIMESTAMP from ‘dataset.table’
);
```

Comment: @Aurangzeb Did my answer help you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Raul! I was hoping for a way to CREATE without the standard SELECT statement. But as you mentioned, dbt does not offer that. I have marked your answer as correct as it does address the issue :) Thank you!!